# How to install KDE5 on Trusty for testing?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, kde

I'm running Kubuntu Trusty (14.04) and am quite happy with it. However, since KDE4 has reached EOL, I should be thiking about upgrading. I don't just want to jump blindly into the cold water but rather first install KDE5 in parallel from where I could revert to my trusted KDE4 desktop any time as required.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Plasma 4 is not co-installable with Plasma 5. By following any tutorials on how to install Plasma 5 in Ubuntu 14.04 it will result in the removal of the Plasma 4 desktop or mess up your whole system.

If you would like to try out Plasma 5, you may want to download a live cd of Kubuntu, and play around with it.